# Problema recibiendo parámetro en Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Con el siguiente script quiero lograr descargar todos los archivos contenidos en un directorio, en este caso, se encuentra dentro del **`public de laravel`**.

Tengo este fragmento de código en una vista Laravel, en el, hay una llamada a un **`helper`**, el cuál escribo más abajo... El problema es que me muestra el siguiente error:

> ErrorException (E_ERROR) file_exists() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, object given, al parecer no recibe el parámetro.

```
@php

$zip = new ZipArchive();

$dir = dir(public_path('/images/events/'.$event->code));

$rutaFinal = dir(public_path('/images/events/downloads/'));

if(!file_exists($rutaFinal)){
  mkdir($rutaFinal);
}

$archivoZip = "file.zip";

if ($zip->open($archivoZip, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) === true) {
  Helper::agregar_zip($dir, $zip);
  $zip->close();

  rename($archivoZip, "$rutaFinal/$archivoZip");

  if (file_exists($rutaFinal. "/" . $archivoZip)) {
    echo "Proceso Finalizado!! <br/><br/>
            Descargar: <a href='$rutaFinal/$archivoZip'>$archivoZip</a>";
  } else {
    echo "Error, archivo zip no ha sido creado!!";
  }
}
@endphp
```

**Función del helper**:

```
public static function agregar_zip($dir, $zip) {
  //verificamos si $dir es un directorio
  if (is_dir($dir)) {
    //abrimos el directorio y lo asignamos a $da
    if ($da = opendir($dir)) {
      //leemos del directorio hasta que termine
      while (($archivo = readdir($da)) !== false) {
        /*Si es un directorio imprimimos la ruta
         * y llamamos recursivamente esta función
         * para que verifique dentro del nuevo directorio
         * por mas directorios o archivos
         */
        if (is_dir($dir . $archivo) && $archivo != "." && $archivo != "..") {
          echo "<strong>Creando directorio: $dir$archivo</strong><br/>";
          agregar_zip($dir . $archivo . "/", $zip);

          /*si encuentra un archivo imprimimos la ruta donde se encuentra
           * y agregamos el archivo al zip junto con su ruta 
           */
        } elseif (is_file($dir . $archivo) && $archivo != "." && $archivo != "..") {
          echo "Agregando archivo: $dir$archivo <br/>";
          $zip->addFile($dir . $archivo, $dir . $archivo);
        }
      }
      //cerramos el directorio abierto en el momento
      closedir($da);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tu problemas es que esta utilizando [dir](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.dir.php) y esto devuelve una instancia de la clase `dir` debes pasarle a `file_exist()` el metodo `path` de `dir` o remover el `dir` y pasar la ruta sola.

**ejemplo:**

```
$rutaFinal = dir(public_path('/images/events/downloads/'));

if(!file_exists($rutaFinal->path)){
  mkdir($rutaFinal);
}
```

**o removiendo dir:**

```
$rutaFinal = public_path('/images/events/downloads/');

if(!file_exists($rutaFinal)){
  mkdir($rutaFinal);
}
```

> nota recomiendo el uso de [is_readable](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.is-readable.php) sobre [file_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.file-exists.php) ya que `file_exists` solo valida que exista mientras que `is_readable` valida que exista y sea legible!